# How can we insert a character to a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, append

INPUT STRING

```
ABCE
```

INPUT CHAR

```
D
```

OUTPUT STRING

```
ABCDE
```

It should run for all sizes , and it should be a standard procedure ie run for all the cases.
Can anyone Help me with this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the `std::string::insert(..)`. Check out the [documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str("ABCE");
    std::cout << str << std::endl; // ABCE

    str.insert(3, 1, 'D');
    std::cout << str << std::endl; // ABCDE

    return -1;
}
```